# Is there any way to migrate delta changes of Azure SQL database from lower environment to higher environment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am using Azure SQL DB as a database in one of the project. I have set up a CI/CD pipeline to migrate the SQL changes from Dev to QA environments (Also to other higher environments)

Currently I am using Azure SQL deployment task to move all changes to the higher environments.

Now I have another requirement where I need to move only delta changes to the higher environments(may be new table addition, stored procedure update etc) ...

Also want to implement version control enabled.

Is there any way to implement using Azure DevOps.

Currently I create a DACPAC from Dev data base followed by Azure SQL data base project creation using visual studio and then performing a build and publish. This entire code I am adding to Azure Repos and then using Azure SQL deployment task I am deploying to the QA environment. The problem with this approach is I am dropping the entire tables, stored procedures , views ...and creating new. I just want to migrate delta changes(differences of Dev and QA)